# How do I create different flavours while using Google Services in Android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio-3.0, google-play-services

I have an app which uses Google Services (I'm connecting to Firebase). I now want to set it up with two different flavours - free and paid.

I've done the following in build.gradle:

```
productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId "myname.appname.free"
        versionName "1.0-free"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "PAID_VERSION", "false"
    }

    paid {
        applicationId "myname.appname.paid"
        versionName "1.0-paid"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "PAID_VERSION", "true"
    }
}
```

From what I've read, syncing this should cause Android Studio do something that sets up the code to 'have' 2 flavours, is that right? The problem is, it won't sync - I get the error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processFreeReleaseGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'myname.appname.free'
```

Everything I've read seems to suggest that I get around this by adding google-services.json into the 'free' and 'paid' folders, but those folders don't exist - maybe Android Studio would set them up if it completed the sync?

Also, in the Firebase console, I currently have one app: myname.appname - do I need to create two apps in there, called myname.appname.free and myname.appname.paid? And download a different google-services.json for each?

Answer (score 4):

You should follow along with the [documentation for the Google Play services plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin).

In particular see the section on [Adding the JSON File](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#adding_the_json_file).  You will have to create your own flavor specific directories:

> The google-services.json file is generally placed in the app/
>   directory (at the root of the Android Studio app module). As of
>   version 2.2.0 the plugin supports build type and product flavor
>   specific JSON files. All of the following directory structures are
>   valid:
>
> ```
> // dogfood and release are build types.
> app/
>     google-services.json
>     src/dogfood/google-services.json
>     src/release/google-services.json
>     ...
> ```
>
> Note: Providing a google-services.json file in the release directory
>   allows you to maintain a separate Firebase project for your production
>   APKs.
>
> When product flavors are in use these more complicated directory
>   structures are also valid.
>
> ```
> // free and paid are product flavors.
> app/
>     google-services.json
>     src/dogfood/paid/google-services.json
>     src/release/free/google-services.json
> ```

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't found that section.